# error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of

Tags: c++, multithreading

I know this type of question has already been asked, but I'm not able figure out the reason for the errors I'm getting..

I'm trying to test a lock implementation as given below using multiple threads:

```
class TTAS
{
    atomic<bool> state;
public:
    TTAS(){
        state =  ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
    }
    void lock() {
        while(true) {
            while(state) {};
            // using exchange() which is equivalent to getAndSet but with lookup
            if (!state.exchange(true)) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    void unlock() {
        state.exchange(false);
    }
};
```

I'm creating threads for this using the below code:

```
void test2(TTAS t) {

}
TTAS t();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    // Create a thread and push it into the thread list and call the distributedWrite function
    threadList.push_back(std::thread(test2, std::ref(t)));
}
```

When I compile this code I get the below error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here..

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:39:0,
                 from assgn4.cpp:17:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(std::reference_wrapper<TTAS()>))(TTAS)>’:
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:137:59:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(TTAS); _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<TTAS()>}]’
assgn4.cpp:186:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::reference_wrapper<TTAS()>))(TTAS)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1526:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::reference_wrapper<TTAS()>))(TTAS)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

Could someone please explain this error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you've encountered the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

```
TTAS t();
```

`t` is a function taking no arguments and returning `TTAS`.

Prefer uniform initialization<sup>1</sup> syntax over the legacy one:

```
TTAS t{}; // no ambiguity here
```

There's one more problem with your code `test2` takes its argument by value, but `TTAS` contains [`std::atomic<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) which is neither copyable nor movable.

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>although this is somewhat a misnomer, as it's not all that uniform</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. I changed the `atomic<bool>` to `atomic<bool>*` which fixed the issue..

Comment: @anirudh my first step would've been making `test2` accept a reference, but I don't know your use case so your solution may be perfectly valid and the best one.

Answer (score 3):

`TTAS t();` is a function declaration. declare it as `TTAS t;` if you want a default-constructed variable.